# SAS graphic appears blurry in EG but not in Base?

Tags: graphics, sas, enterprise-guide

For some reason, the exact same code written in SAS Base 9.4 and Enterprise Guide 7.1 produce different pdf outputs in terms of quality. While both of them appears perfect inside the program (result window), only Base outputs a similar pdf results. The EG version is about the double size but very blurry.

Do you have any ideas? I find it very weird.

```
data normal (keep=x);
call streaminit(4321);
  do i=1 to 2000;
  x=rand("normal")*100;
  output;
end;
output;
run;

title 'Distribution of Blood Pressure';

ods graphics on / border=off ;
ods pdf file="C:\....\base.pdf" notoc dpi=300;

proc sgplot data=normal;
histogram x / fillattrs=graphdata3 transparency=0.7 binstart=40 binwidth=10;
density x / lineattrs=graphdata4;
density x / type=kernel lineattrs=graphdata5;
keylegend / location=inside position=topright noborder across=2;
yaxis grid;
run;
ods pdf close;
```

Comment: You're welcome to attach screenshots, but please don't use third party services like that to post images - StackOverflow should be hosting the image.

Comment: You should also include notations in your question regarding what EG is hooked up to - is it hooked up to the local install, or a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to verify which graphics driver is being used in the two systems.  Enterprise Guide has a setting (Tools -> Options -> Results -> Graph -> Graph Format) which controls the driver that will be used by default; Base SAS has a similar setting (`OPTIONS DEVICE=`) which will do the same.  You probably don't set it in Base SAS, while EG definitely does set it (to its default, which I believe is different from Base SAS's default).

Try changing it to different settings in the two systems - or to the same setting - and you should be able to see what differences it makes.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused. I have downloaded the two files that you shared, but I can't see any difference in how crisp the graphs are. the only difference is that one has a title and the other one doesn't. The title has a small impact on the rest of the graph.

See the screenshots attached.

Regards,
Vasilij

[image]
[image]